# Can an input show options to select, using @input?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, primevue

I am working with vu3, I am using the primevue library... more specifically I am using its InputText component... and what I am looking to do is that when I add, for example, the character $ in the input... there will be a list of options (data that I plan to bring from the backend: ${{field}}) ... I do not use a select because if the character $ is not typed I need to capture what the user types ... they told me that I could do it with the input event.

primevue InputText component link: https://primevue.org/inputtext/

```
<template>
  <div class="mt-6">
    <InputText
      type="text"
      v-model="value"
      @input="prueba($event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const prueba = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
};
</script>
```

This is what I'm looking for:
[image]

Comment: You should consider using the AutoComplete component instead of InputText, docs: https://primevue.org/autocomplete/